# a computer program does what for the user - Technical writing

Tags: technical

I am writing a technical document and, I have a module called "Pre-policy Module" which is a web application(like, say, facebook).

What could be appropriate to say in a sentence like this:

> The goal of VAS – Pre policy Web Application is to automate the process of
>   appointment scheduling, rescheduling, cancelling, ...

It is obviously not "automate" because parts of it require manual operation. What word can I substitute in place of "automate"?

Comment: *is to facilitate automation of the process* - Will it help?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Writing advice requests are off topic (see [FAQ]). Try Writers.SE but please check their FAQ before posting. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

*aid*, *simplify*, *assist*, *help* or synonyms of those (I'd avoid *facilitate*, which would be technically correct, but is overused IMO).

You could certainly say that it automates particular parts of the process.

Answer (score 2):

I would also remove *goal*. The module has no goals, the programmer who wrote it has goals, but not the software itself. Perhaps something like

> The VAS – Pre policy Web Application *manages* appointment scheduling, rescheduling, cancelling, ...

Answer (score 1):

*[streamline](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/streamline?q=streamline)*

> make (an organization or system) more efficient and effective by employing faster or simpler working methods

Comment: Whom are you citing?

Comment: Good point @tchrist. I have added a link to the cited definition.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps *[coordinate](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/coordinate?q=coordinate)*

> bring the different elements of (a complex activity or organization) into a relationship that will ensure efficiency or harmony.